# how to use div as dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let's say that I have a code like this and I want this to work like dropdown one by one

something like:

```
ABCD

ABCD
  1234

ABCD
  1234
    abcd
```

```html
<ul class="first">
  <li class="first-a"><a href="https://someurl">ABCD</a>
    <ul class="second">
      <li class="second-a"><a href="https://someurl">1234</a>
        <ul class="third">
          <li class="third-a"><a href="https://someurl">abcd</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I used css something like this

```
.first li {
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.second {
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
}
.second.open {
  display: block;
}
```

and js like this

```
$( ".first-a" ).click(function() {
  $(".second").removeClass( "open" );
  $(".second", this).toggleClass( "open" );
});
$(window).click(function() {
 $(".second" ).removeClass( "open" );
});
$(".first-a").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and nothing of this worked till now

Comment: so what have you tried to accomplish this ?

Comment: I tried using display elements and some js which one of my friend gave me but none of that worked

Comment: well...post here what you have tried. and let's go from there

Comment: It's not very clear what you are expecting - the snippet looks like your something like area

Comment: @Pete I want theese list tags to work like a dropdown menu one after another

Comment: so when you click on the li, it opens it sub ul?

Comment: @Pete yes exactly that

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind a click to the li (may want to give it a class so that it doesn't apply to every li in your project)  then you can use jquery to remove the open class from every sibling li and then toggle the class of the one that was clicked.

```js
$("li").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();        // prevents the link click firing otherwise you just redirect to the link and no animation will happen
  e.stopPropagation();       // prevents child clicks bubbling up to parent+
  var $thisLi = $(this);     // get the current li that was clicked as a jquery object
  $thisLi.parent().children('li').not($thisLi).removeClass( "open"); // remove class from all sibling lis but not clicked
  $thisLi.toggleClass( "open");                                      // toggle the class on the clicked
});
```

```css
li {
  position: relative;
}

li>ul {
  display:none;  /* start sub menus hidden */
}

li.open>ul {
  display:block;  /* show sub menu when open class is added to parent li */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first">
  <li class="first-a"><a href="https://someurl">ABCD</a>
    <ul class="second">
      <li class="second-a"><a href="https://someurl">1234</a>
        <ul class="third">
          <li class="third-a"><a href="https://someurl">abcd</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="first-a"><a href="https://someurl">ABCD</a>
    <ul class="second">
      <li class="second-a"><a href="https://someurl">1234</a>
        <ul class="third">
          <li class="third-a"><a href="https://someurl">abcd</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am not that good at js so please elaborate, I am having trouble applying this code

Comment: how can I elaborate any more - there are comments explaining each line of code